# apt-get command not found - bitbucket pipelines

Tags: docker, bitbucket, aws-cli, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to setup my cicd pipeline with bitbucket pipeline, I need to install `jq` in one of the steps in order to format a file. However, I get `bash: apt-get: command not found` error.

Below is my bitbucket pipeline

```
pipelines:
  custom: # Pipelines that can only be triggered manually
    push-build-to-ecr:
      - step:
          name: Build & Push Image
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - docker
          script:
            - export SERVICE_NAME=my-node-service
            - export SERVICE_BRANCH=$BITBUCKET_BRANCH
            - export TAG_LATEST=$SERVICE_BRANCH-latest
            - printenv > .env.common
            # Remove lines with spaces in env file
            - sed -i -e '/ /d' .env.common
            - docker build --tag $SERVICE_NAME:$TAG_LATEST --target=production-stage .
            - docker images
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-ecr-push-image:2.0.0
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                IMAGE_NAME: $SERVICE_NAME
                TAGS: $TAG_LATEST
          artifacts:
            - .env.common

      - step:
          name: Validate Task Definitions
          image: atlassian/pipelines-awscli
          script:
            - source .env.common
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get install -y jq
            - eval $(aws ecr get-login --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} --no-include-email)            
          artifacts:
            - .env.common

      - step:
          name: Deploy to ECS
          script:
            - echo "Deploy to ECS"
```

Answer (score 4):

Some docker images do not stem from Debian images but other distros like Alpine, which is the case for the `atlassian/pipelines-awscli` you are using.

You can't assume the presence of a particular package manager in a docker image. You can't even assume the presence of any package manager at all!

Just do

```
apk update
apk add jq
```

### Pro-tips

#### 1

`atlassian/pipelines-awscli` is outdated and deprecated in favor of `amazon/aws-cli`, which is maintained by Amazon, see https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/pipelines-awscli

Note that `amazon/aws-cli` does not feature either `apt` nor `apk` but `yum`, so you should do this instead:

```
yum update
yum install --assumeyes jq
```

#### 2

Any `aws-cli` subcommand can be passed a `--query` option to extract values from the responses with JMESPath so it is pretty much almost as powerful as `jq`, to the extent that `jq` is often only installed out of lack of awareness about this.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html#cli-usage-filter-client-side

Comment: After `- yum install --assumeyes jq`, I still get `bash: apt-get: command not found`.